# 90s fantasy movie: winged demons dragging a man under furniture, followed by a splash of blood

Tags: story-identification, movie

It's a fantasy movie from the late 90s I think but I'm not too sure.

There are some winged demons that drag a man underneath a piece of furniture then the next scene shows a huge splash of blood.

I always thought it was in a *Dungeons&Dragons* movie, but I searched throughout the whole films in vain. Maybe I missed something.

I saw it on TV. The overall atmosphere was very similar to *Dungeons and Dragons* from 2000 and I could have sworn Jeremy Irons was playing a role, but when I searched the whole movie I couldn't find said scene. Someone in the movie had called some winged demons from a tower to attack or retrieve something from a castle's library.

Comment: Perhaps Julian Sands, who looks a bit like Jeremy Irons? That might make the movie Warlock (1989) https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098622/ - although I don't recall a scene like the one you describe.

Comment: Whoever's voting to close as too broad, please provide a couple of 90s movies with such a scene. So far it's terse, but not so much as broad

Answer (score 7):

I FOUND IT! It was a scene from [*Dungeons and Dragons 2: The Wrath of the Dragon God*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0406728/).

> Based on the phenomenally successful role-playing game, Dungeons & Dragons 2 takes you deeper into the dark and fantastical world of this fantasy epic. When the evil sorcerer Damodar braves a perilous whirlwind vortex to steal the elemental black orb he declares a sinister plan of vengeance against the kingdom of Ismir. Berek, a decorated warrior, and Melora, an amateur sorceress join four heroes representing Intelligence, Wisdom, Honor and Strength to battle against Damodar's growing army of gruesome creatures, flying harpies and an ice dragon to reach a vault room holding the orb. Together, they build their own army to retrieve the orb using elemental forces to defeat Damodar before he summons the sleeping black dragon whose omnipotent evil powers could lay waste to the entire kingdom.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to tell us what this is! You should be able to accept this 48 hours after you posted the question so in ~38 hours if I worked that out correctly, please do so!

Comment: Just so you are aware in the future you can [edit] your own posts to add that information in yourself!

Answer (score 1):

A few years later, but Eragon (2006) had a broadly similar feel and featured Jeremy Irons in a lead role. I know the protagonists family are killed - I can't remember if that's the scene you describe but it would fit with the overall plot. There is at least one secondary villain who either summons or turns into a winged demon.

Trailer here:

Comment: No.. It's not Eragon (I know that movie well) or Warlock. Remember, the movie is set in a complete fantasy world. Hmmm...  The winged demons were shorter than a man in stature, with a skinny appearance and long yellow claws and yellowish bright featureless eyes. Something an 80's / 90's movie style would portray in its special effects.